# How to get started with svn:externals?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, externals

I'm looking for a succinct and well-written tutorial on using svn:externals.

I already know how to use them in a basic way myself, but I want a good article that I can link to when answering questions like this one that come up recently:

[What to do with multiple projects depending on the same source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662898/what-to-do-with-multiple-projects-depend-on-the-same-source/662905)

I'd do it myself, but I don't use them often enough to want to stick my neck out and write a tutorial on it.  Google was surprisingly unhelpful with this topic.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Here are some sections about it in the svnbook /  TortoiseSVN manual:

[This](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html) is the svnbook page on svn:externals. It is the most useful resource on the subject.

[This one](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-common-projects.html#tsvn-howto-common-externals) explains four ways to include sub-projects in the workflow (and in the process misses a fifth one: symlinks).

And [this last one](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-import.html#tsvn-dug-import-4) is a TortoiseSVN-specific page on how to import stuff in a repository (not directly related to svn:externals).

Answer (score 23):

In case it isn't clear from the links provided above, the way you set the `svn:externals` property that is tied to a particular revision (pinning), here it is:

```
svn propset svn:externals "plugins -r12345 https://svn.example.com/common/plugins" extras
```

That will will make a `plugins` subdirectory under the `extras` directory and link it to revision `12345` of the external SVN URL `https://svn.example.com/common/plugins`.

There is a Red Bean article that suggests using `propedit` since the `svn:externals` can be a multi-line value. The above example would be changed as follows to use `propedit`.

```
svn propedit svn:externals extras
```

You would then add one line for each external link following the same format shown above for the value.

Comment: The positioning of the quotes is the key to getting propset to work.  Without the quotes, all sorts of errors are generated.

Answer (score 0):

```
root/repo1/proj/base/common/log.c
root/repo1/proj/base/common/log.h
root/repo1/proj/base/client

root/repo2/proj/test/base
```

As show above, we want to copy 2 files and 1 directory to `repo2`

> Step1
>
> directory: /home/jack/repo2/proj/

```
cd /home/jack
```

> Step2

```
svn propset svn:externals "../repo1/proj/base/client proj/base/client" repo2
```

something like: `ln repo1/proj/base/client repo2/proj/base/client`

> Step3

```
export SVN_EDITOR=vim
```

> Step4

```
svn propedit svn:externals repo2
```

vim shows :

../repo1/proj/base/client proj/base/client

> Step5: add another two files

```
../repo1/proj/base/client proj/base/client
../repo1/proj/base/common/log.c proj/base/common/log.c
../repo1/proj/base/common/log.h proj/base/common/log.h
```