# SVN - Project in multiple solutions

Tags: c#, svn, project, solution

Is there a way to share a project across multiple solutions in SVN? I already have a class library in a solution that I want to import in another one. Can I just import the project in the new solution or will there be a problem with paths (since the project is not in the same repository)? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll add another `externals` link:

[How to get started with svn:externals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663155/how-to-get-started-with-svnexternals)

Comment: Nice, answering with your own question ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want [svn:externals](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-externals.html).

Answer (score -1):

look at svn externals

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externals.html

Comment: That link is very old, externals were updated in 1.6 (file based) and 1.5 (relative pathing).  Just because google is fast, doesn't mean it's always right ;-)

Comment: my bad. the basic concept still applies though. maybe he's still running 1.0 :)