# Virtual copies of files in SVN?

Tags: svn

I'm guesing if its possible to have virtual copies of my code with SVN. For example: imagine that I have two programs in my repository. Program A use a subset of files used by B.

My question is if I could update a copy of a file in the context of program A, then commit in SVN and next time I update my code, I have the same copy in program A and B without the need to copy by hand this file.

It is posible?
some help would be welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look into [externals](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-common-projects.html#tsvn-howto-common-externals) - there's also a post here on [how to get started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663155/how-to-get-started-with-svnexternals).

Answer (score 0):

If you could use a special directory construction you could just check out your B to your A,
then add it to ignore in A.
Then you can update in B directory.