# How do you share libs using subversion the best way?

Tags: c#, vb.net, svn, frameworks

My goal is to create a subversion repository with the following layout

- project Template (docs , mail , ... source , etc.)
- Common (things that can be shared around on other projects).
- project A
- project B
- etc.. ....

The idea is based on http://www.autumnofagile.net/ part 0-B

However there they use a Vault-control.

So the main question is : Is it possible to share a folder (on subversion ) so other people get it. and Subversion doesn't become a Copy-paste zone.

The reason for this is that the project is C#/vb.net (so Maven is out of the game).

Or is there another strategy to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look into svn:externals:

- http://claudio.cicali.name/post/2005/10/svnexternals-micro-howto/
- http://e-mats.org/2008/05/adding-an-external-svn-resource-with-tortoise/
- [How to get started with svn:externals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663155/how-to-get-started-with-svnexternals)

Comment: Svn externals is great, but if your libraries end up being quite interdependent then it can be a bit of a struggle to keep things straight. For dependencies that I don't control, I put those in a Library folder in my solution and commit those binaries along with the project source. This simplifies automated build, unit testing and so on. For dependencies that I _do_ control, I have taken to using svn copy to fork a copy of the dependency into the source tree of each solution. Each copy is effectively a branch and can always pick up changes from the trunk. YMMV.