# How to do PhoneGap cross platform

Tags: cordova, mobile, cross-platform

I'm know that I'm going to ask an stupid question. But well, I need your help.

I'm planning and designing my first Mobile app, and I heard a lot about phone gap, so I decide to give it a try.

So, I started googling it and seeing tutorials, and all the information that I get is for:
Phonegap for Android
Phonegap for iPhone

So, I don't understand why is that, if the code should be the same for both. Or almost similar, maybe some specific sentences for each OS.

I get that for iphone I have to use x-code and for android eclipse.

But How can I make my application and then generate the build for Android and then for iphone? (or that was what I imaged)
I mean, develop the application for both (and also the other SOs) at the same time.

Is that possible?

Apart from that, do you have a favorite tutorial that wants to share with me?

Last question, Can I make application with a superb UI design and usuability or is phonegap a bit limited for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For tutorials, simply use the Phonegap ones here : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_getting-started_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20Guides

Just use the tutorial related to the Platform that you aim.

About Phonegap and devlopping one app for each OS : when you create a "Phonegap project" using one of the tutorial, you create a file structure that allows you to deploy your application on the choosen Platform. But inside of this architecture, there is a "Assets" folder that contains your HTML5/CSS3/Javascript code. This code could be simply copy/paste to other Platform projects to be reuse.

In fact, you create a projet for each OS but you duplicate your core code.

About your last question : there is no Phonegap limitation for the design because you just use HTML5/CSS3/Javascript like making a website... but like a website, you will have some CSS differences between Platforms and you will have to fix it like you do for a website.

Hope this helps ! Bye !

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to share the assets folder for the different platforms... (I prefer not to duplicate code in repositories, nor locally)

On local machine you can use a symbolic link to this folder (I gues in windows that's just a shortcut to a dir)

In the repository you could choose to use a different repository entry for the assets folder and include it in your different platfomrs

for git: use git submodules: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

for svn: use svn externals: create a dir in your svn dir, after having committed it, use svn properties and create an entry svn:externals: [How to get started with svn:externals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663155/how-to-get-started-with-svnexternals)