# Add project from different solution with all previous commits

Tags: visual-studio, svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

I have project A in solution1 and project B in solution2. I want to add project B to solution1 with all the previous versions(commits) of the project B.

How can this be done?

Comment: Your question is a little confusing... previous versions of what? Not sure also what svn has to do here...

Comment: Right click on the solution header, Add -> Existing Project, and select the project file.  What do you mean by all the previous versions of project B?  You can do this for all your branches/tags, however you cannot change SVN history.

Comment: Is your question "How do I create a branch in SVN"?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to make Solution1/ProjectB an external link via [svn:externals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663155/how-to-get-started-with-svnexternals) property on the local folder. This will yield one physical location and two logical locations in your repository.