# Keep tags folder outside project folder in subversion

Tags: svn

My company uses subversion. We use the tags folder in order to:

> Store a picture of what the customer has on it's server, so that if we have to fix a bug or do any activity we know exactly what the client has

Since tags are immutable versions of an application, we think that the use we make of the tags folder is correct.

Now we are moving the repository and thinking about improving it's management a bit; a best practice doubt has arisen about **WHERE** to put the tags folder.

At the moment, the structure we are using is the classic one, i.e this:

[image]

But part of the refactoring/cleaning team suggests to try this way:

[image]

In the second structure, it would be clearer which products the customer have. In case of tech support activity, developers would directly look for the customer's folder within tags, no need to know from a colleague which products the client has and then trace those tags by entering all project's folder individually.

Which structure is the clearest and the more maintainable?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

### Preface

**There are not** such thing as "classic layout" of SVN-repository, there are only some recommended for different use-cases with own sets of "pro" et "contra" and you can select any or create own. Anyway, "branches", "tags", "trunk" is just a *conventional way* to use different parts of repository tree for different purposes - you can build own tree even with own names for your needs and habits.

### Face

While second picture seems more *nice* for eyes, it can have some rake in the grass under the some conditions.

Think about these:

- Will it be giant monolithic SUPER-REPO with root *above* `ProjectN`|`Tags` folders (with all inherited problems of super-repo - global versioning, shared hooks)? SVN-admin **will not thank you** for a such headache
- Will it be a set of independent (tags separated from dev-line) repo? Are you ready for cross-repository commits (it's possible, but... *with not obvious tricks*)?
- Will you ready to *various particulars*, forgotten by me here and now?

From my POV, best (easy, manageable, natural) approach will be using (PEG-ed?) SVN-externals, with which you can add additional custom tree (Client -> Project -> Snapshot) from existing objects outside development-area

### Future Reading

[Externals Definitions](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.externals.html) from SVN Book

[How to get started with svn:externals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663155/how-to-get-started-with-svnexternals) from here

---

[Peg and Operative Revisions](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html) from SVN Book

Comment: i don't think bullet point 1 is our case. And neither point 2, we have only one repository for all company's products. About point 3, clearly it's difficult to predict every single possible consequences of a given architecture(that said, we'll go for the least worst). About what we should do(from "From my POV" on. Can you be more clear? Images maybe? What does PEG-ed means? Google can't seem to help us neither) thanks