# Phonegap sourcecode repository structure

Tags: cordova

We are setting up a sourcecode repository for a Phonegap app (it will be SVN, but I try to be repository independent in my question). The Phonegap app will be build for Android, iPhone and Windows Phone.

In my understanding these application share all the content of the www directory, but have a different native app structure.

So, how should I set up the repository structure? All developers should have the same www directory, but each developer should work with his platform only? How can this be done?

Any help is appreciated.
Kind regards, Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such a situation one could use svn external.

Put the content of the www folder into one repository and the platforms into one per platform.

The platform repos use the www folder as svn external.

A good starting point for svn external is this stackoverflow question: [What to do with multiple projects depending on the same source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662898/what-to-do-with-multiple-projects-depending-on-the-same-source/662905#662905)