# Combining multiple SVN repositories with single folders for trunk branches tags

Tags: svn, repository

I am working on a piece of software that has four different projects. Each of these projects is stored in a separate SVN repository, with a trunk and two branches.

So it looks like this

```
repo1
    trunk
        src
    branches
        branch1
            src
        branch2
            src

etc...

repo4
    trunk
        src
    branches
        branch1
            src
        branch2
            src
```

What I want to do is combine these repositories into a single repository so that I can do switches, merges, and history in a single repository and not have do deal with four different ones.

So I envision it looking like this in the end

```
repo
    trunk
        project1
            src
        etc...
        project4
            src
    branches
        branch1
            project1
                src
            etc...
            project4
                src
        branch2
            project1
                src
            etc...
            project4
                src
```

Is it possible to do this? I have looked at [Combining multiple SVN repositories into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267256/combining-multiple-svn-repositories-into-one) which discusses how to have `trunk` `branches` `tags` inside each project, but I would like the projects to be contained within the different standard SVN folders (unless there is a good reason not to).

Comment: If you want it including history, it would require a lot of rewriting the output of `svnadmin dump` (at least `Node-path` & `Node-copyfrom-path`, but there may be others. Doable, but time-consuming. The other solution you linked to is a helluvalot easier. It would even be easier to load the paths in that link & then just manually mv them to the desired location if the total number of tags/branches isn't that high.

Comment: So if I do that then it would break the history?

Comment: No, with the _"including history"_, what I meant to say was I assume you want that (because otherwise, well, you can just set up the desired tree in a filesystem in do 1 huge commit. Neither of the mentioned solutions break the history, although when you make an error in rewriting the `dump` you might accidentally break something.

Comment: @Wrikken used your second suggestion and it worked like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the answer on the question I linked and suggestions from Wrikken, I managed to get this working.

The first step is to dump the existing repositories

```
svnadmin dump > project1.dmp
```

now create a new folder in the combined repo

```
svn mkdir http://myserver/svn/repo/project1
```

then load them into the new repository

```
svnadmin load --parent-dir "project1" < project1.dmp
```

now go into `project1` folder and move

```
svn mv http://myserver/svn/repo/project1/trunk http://myserver/svn/repo/trunk/project1
svn mv http://myserver/svn/repo/branches/branch1 http://myserver/svn/repo/branches/branch1/project1
```

now delete the `project1` directory

```
svn delete http://myserver/svn/repo/project1
```

and do the same for the other repos you want to merge.