# renumber versions in SVN repository after combine

Tags: svn, repository, tortoisesvn

I have 2 separate repositories on my SVN server, but actually its for one project. I now want to combine/merge both Repos into one. I already found a solution to do this [Combining multiple SVN repositories into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267256/combining-multiple-svn-repositories-into-one)

Problem is still that after i combine the repo_A and repo_B into repo_C the version numbers are not in the correct order.

I was wondering if it is possible to drop all the revision numbers and create new numbers accordingly to the date of the original commit

Answer (score 0):

> if it is possible to drop all the revision numbers and create new numbers

No. And it's good: parent-child relation doesn't mirror older|newer for unrelated previously repositories