# Combining multiple SVN repositories while maintaining chronological history

Tags: svn, sharpsvn

I have been trying to find a way to combine multiple SVN repositories into a single repository while maintaining overall chronological history. I currently have a folder with only the dumps of each repository. I am using SharpSVN to create a helper program to do this for me.

The repositories look like this:

- Root

  - Branches
  - Tags
  - Trunk

And I wish to combine them into a structure like so:

- Root

  - ProjectA

    - Branches
    - Tags
    - Trunk
  - ProjectB

    - Branches
    - Tags
    - Trunk

  etc

I have come across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267256/combining-multiple-svn-repositories-into-one), which almost does what I want but fails when maintaining chronological order (in the revision history it would look like ProjectA was worked on and finished, then ProjectB was added, then ProjectC, etc).

One of the answers I've gotten was to load each dump into a temporary repository, check out the repository, re-dump each revision by date (rinse and repeat for all repositories) then load each one of these mini-dumps in chronological order into the actual repository. Is there a better way to do this? Is there any way I could read each dump file for the next chronological revision, load that specific revision, and continue?

Comment: Is the C# tag relevant here?

Comment: I guess not really - this is my first question on StackOverflow so I just added any tags I felt were relevant. I am using C# with SharpSVN though.