# Is it possible to merge mutliple Subversion repositories into one without changing revisions

Tags: svn

We do have three repositories that we would like to merge into a single one. Currently we do have three repositories that look like this:

- Repository X

  - Project 1

    - branches
    - tags
    - trunk
  - Project 2

    - branches
    - tags
    - trunk

We want to merge all three into a single repository that looks like this:

- Repository root

  - Repository A

    - Project 1

      - branches
      - tags
      - trunk
    - Project 2

      - branches
      - tags
      - trunk
  - Repository B

    - Project 1

      - branches
      - tags
      - trunk
    - Project 2

      - branches
      - tags
      - trunk
  - Repository C

    - Project 1

      - branches
      - tags
      - trunk
    - Project 2

      - branches
      - tags
      - trunk

After some research we found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/267284/11837055) answer here and [this](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#multi-merge) one in the official Apache FAQ. Judging by these two sources it is not possible but maybe there is a workaround?

Comment: I think it's impossible. What would be the revision 1 inside `root`? The `A` repos revision 1 or `B` or `C`?