# Combine two SVN repositories and sort their revisions together in chronological order

Tags: svn

I have two SVN repositories that have been in use for some years by the same team. I want to merge these into a single repository. I'm totally okay with their revision numbers getting re-assigned. In fact, I want that to happen because I need the revisions in these two repositories to be blended together in chronological order.

The solutions in this other post do not work for me as they don't assign the revision numbers in chronological order: [Combining multiple SVN repositories into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267256/combining-multiple-svn-repositories-into-one)

What I get if I just load two repositories' dump files into a third, empty repository is the first-loaded repository's revision numbers come first and then, totally out of chronological order with the first repo/dump's revisions, the second-loaded repository's revisions are assigned revision numbers. Like this:

[image]

In my image above, the dark red numeric call-outs are the expected/desired revision numbers — the ones I would get if these two repos' revisions were blended in chronological order.

Accuracy: If two commits are at the same second/microsecond (whatever SVN revision's maximum time accuracy is), I don't care which one is first and which one is second in the revision numbers that get assigned during this process.

Answer (score 0):

SvnDumpTool's "merge" argument handles exactly this. I tested it just now and it worked!
https://svn.borg.ch/svndumptool/